# using qtip to replace ALL title attributes on a page

Tags: jquery, qtip

If there a way to have all title attributes become qtips?

Right now I'm just going through and finding all the tags that need to be done but this is slow and not reliable.

instead of this

```
$(document).ready(ImportantFunction);
    function ImportantFunction() {
        Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
            $find("ctl31").add_propertyChanged(viewerPropertyChanged);
        });
    }

    function viewerPropertyChanged(sender, e) {
        if (e.get_propertyName() === "isLoading") {
            var viewer = $find("ctl31");
            if (!viewer.get_isLoading())
            {
                $('table[title]').qtip();
                $('td[title]').qtip();
                $('input[title]').qtip();
                $('a[title]').qtip();
            }
        }
    }//*/
```

I just want to call it once if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
$('[title]').qtip();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.
Unfortunately it's now too slow. IE complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using $.each() instead?  It probably seems trivial and similar but it also may go faster since you're only calling qTip on a (hopefully) smaller subset:

```
  $('[title]').each(function() {
      this.qtip({
           // init here
      });
 });
```

Note that you can also comma-separate your selectors, so you could simply do:

```
  $('table[title],td[title],input[title],a[title]').each(function() {
      this.qtip({
           // init here
      });
 });
```

Or even:

```
  $('table[title],td[title],input[title],a[title]').qtip();
```